# How to display the number of items present is a list using loop

Tags: android

I have a list having number of questions in it. 
I want to display the total no. of question present in the list.

Comment: use the size() method to determine the size of an collection(list, map, set...)

Comment: by list you mean `ListView` or `ArrayList` ?

Comment: @Mohit yes, list is a interface which is implemented by arraylist etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop is used to get particular element at particular index like :

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();       
for(Object obj : list){
   //---- do  something with obj
}
```

You do not need loop for size, there are methods to get size of collected data.

Well it not clear which list you are referring to, but here is some example of how you can get size/length of collected data..

if you are referring to `ListView`,use `getCount()`  :

```
//        --------------ListView
ListView listView = new ListView(context);
int listViewSize = listView.getCount();
```

And if your referring to any Collection , use `size()` :

```
//        --------------Collection
ArrayList<?> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
int arrayListSize = arrayList.size();

List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
int listSize = list.size();

Set<?> stringSet = new HashSet<>();
int setSize = stringSet.size();

Map<?,?> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
int mapSize = hashMap.size();

LinkedList<?> link = new LinkedList<>();
int linkedListSize = link.size();

Queue<?> queue = new LinkedList<>();
int queueSize = queue.size();
```

`<?>` indicate generic, use data-type (`<String>,<Integer>` etc) for particular return type..

Any other data type array, use `length` :

```
//        ---------------Data Type 
String[] stringsArray = new String[]{};
int stringArraySize = stringsArray.length;

int[] in = new int[]{};
int intSize = in.length;
```

[This is java document for explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

use `size()` method to get the size of the list

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the below. Although the question is not clear.

```
for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
```